# difference between Price and Base Price

Tags: price

In magento sales quote,

There's `price` and `base_price` and I can't find the difference between the two

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Price is the value in the selected store currency

Base Price is the value in the default store currency.

If you have only one currency on your website then base_price and price should always have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

the price can be in another currency the base_price is the price in the base currency entered in backend of magento